# Keycloak User SPI Migration Strategy Import - Failing at importing credentials

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm working on migrating out of an old database store. We've created a user storage SPI that allows us to use the old system to validate credentials. This currently works. We validate the credentials in our custom CredentialInputValidator.isValid function. What we want to do is, the login to the old system is valid, we want to create a local user account matching the user and attach credentials.

The way this should work, as I understand it, is:

```
Login ->
        -> Hits Custom User Storage SPI
        -> On Success
            -> Create local user account if not exists
            -> Attach new password credentials
        -> Is Logged In
    Log Out
    Log In ->
        -> Checks Keycloak Local Users
            -> User Storage SPI is never checked, because the local account was previously created.
        -> UN/PW check
            -> (failure happens here)
        -> Is Logged In
```

This is how it SHOULD work. Unfortunately, no matter what I try, it never lets me log in the second time (nor does it ever attempt to hit the User Storage SPI again, because the local account exists). I can see that the user and credentials were created in the realm under users; I can see the user and credential rows in public.user_entity and public.credential tables.

No matter what I try, I can never log in to the local account.

Below is my isValid function. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, CredentialInput input) {
            UserCredentialModel cred = (UserCredentialModel)input;
            String password = cred.getValue();
    
            // Login to the legacy system.
            String loginOutput = loginCMD(user.getUsername(), password, xForwardedFor);
    
            // Falures return a simple string "false"
            Boolean valid = !loginOutput.equals("false");
    
            if (!valid) {
                return valid;
            }
    
            // Store the user back to Keycloak.
            UserModel local = UserStoragePrivateUtil.userLocalStorage(session).getUserByUsername(realm, user.getUsername());
    
            if (local != null) {
                return valid;
            }
    
            local = UserStoragePrivateUtil.userLocalStorage(session).addUser(realm, user.getUsername());
            local.setFirstName("firstName");
            local.setLastName("lastName");
            local.setEmail(user.getUsername());
            local.setEnabled(true);
            local.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    
            Pbkdf2PasswordHashProvider encoder = new Pbkdf2PasswordHashProvider(
                Pbkdf2Sha512PasswordHashProviderFactory.ID,
                Pbkdf2Sha512PasswordHashProviderFactory.PBKDF2_ALGORITHM,
                Pbkdf2Sha512PasswordHashProviderFactory.DEFAULT_ITERATIONS,
                256 // Tried setting this to 512, as well, no dice.
            );
    
            PasswordCredentialModel pcm = encoder.encodedCredential(password, Pbkdf2Sha512PasswordHashProviderFactory.DEFAULT_ITERATIONS);
    
            Date date = new Date();
            pcm.setCreatedDate(date.getTime());
            pcm.setUserLabel("user-spi migration");
    
            if (!local.credentialManager().isConfiguredFor(input.getType())) {
                try {
                    local.credentialManager().createStoredCredential(pcm);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    
            return valid;
        }
```

I tried creating a local user with a credential, and logging in using that account. The account and credential get created, but login always fails with

> DEBUG [org.keycloak.credential.PasswordCredentialProvider] (executor-thread-1) Failed password validation for user [redacted]